# GroupBy with ternary operator

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a Person object:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public bool IsTest { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have a list filled with different `Person` objects.

I want to know is there a way to use ternary operator with GroupBy in LINQ depending on some property of object. For example:

```
var groupedPersons = persons.GroupBy(person => person.IsTest ? 
                      new {
                              person.Name, 
                              person.Age, 
                              person.Address
                           } 
                     : new {
                              person.Name, 
                              person.Age, 
                              person.Address, 
                              person.Height}).ToList();
```

But unfortunately that doesn't work, gives me exception

> Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is
>   no implicit conversion between 'AnonymousType#1' and 'AnonymousType#2'

Is this achievable at all and how?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Tried this, but not working.

```
var groupedPersons = persons.GroupBy(person => person.OnTest ? 
                     new Person { 
                                   Address = person.Address, 
                                   Name = person.Name, 
                                   Age = person.Age } 
                     : new Person { 
                                   Address= person.Address, 
                                   Name = person.Name, 
                                   Age = person.Age , 
                                   Height = person.Height}).ToList();
```

**EDIT:** Got it to work, look at my answer

Comment: have you tried selecting new "Persons" instead of using anonymous classes?

Comment: I'm surprised that selecting Person's works, unless your person class implements Equals() and GetHashCode(). If this is EF, then I'm pretty sure it won't let you select new instances of an entity class.

Comment: yeah, you are right, this is not working correctly, but I managed to get it to work :) Look at my answer...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ok, after trying some examples shown here I realized that this is not gonna work and I got it to work other way. Here's an example how I did it:

```
var groupedPersons = 
       persons.GroupBy(
                 person =>
                      person.Name + "|" +
                      person.Age.ToString() + "|" +
                      person.Address + "|" +
                      (person.IsTest ? null : person.Height.ToString())
      .ToList();
```

So if there's a Person with property `IsTest = false` then it uses `person.Height` to group also.

Comment: Doing it this way is a bad idea, string is not some general type that you should use to represent anything.

Comment: Actually in my real object (that's in project not the Person here) all properties that are grouped by are strings. And one boolean property also. Then depending on boolean value, I need to group by one more property or not.

Comment: So I asked, is this achievable and how - and I found one solution to it. I can change properties of my example Person class to strings too if this is a problem and downvoting case.

Comment: That's not the issue that some of the properties are not strings. The issue is that you shouldn't use strings to represent structured data if you don't have to.

Comment: `Name: Barack|51 Age: 51 Address: The White House` would get grouped with `Name: Barack Age: 51 Address: 51|The White House`.  It may seem unlikely to happen, but it is good practice to minimize all potential errors.  But I realize that this is the only solution that worked for you.  What was wrong with [my solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12519962/480799)?  I believe my edited version deals with any potential issues.

Comment: Actually I group the string with "||" in real project. Your example wasn't sorting correctly. If there was 3 persons, then there was 3 groups, altough that 2 of them was in the same group.

Comment: @evilone But you can see how grouping using strings can result in things being grouped incorrectly, right?  And what were the values that didn't work?

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use anonymous objects.  You just have to make sure they have the same field names and field types:

```
var groupedPersons = persons.GroupBy(person => person.IsTest ? 
                      new {
                              person.Name, 
                              person.Age, 
                              person.Address,
                              Height = 0
                           } 
                     : new {
                              person.Name, 
                              person.Age, 
                              person.Address, 
                              person.Height}).ToList();
```

**Edit:** Now that I think about it you can save some lines of code by using the ternary operator when assigning `Height`.  If you're worried about people with height 0 being grouped with test people, you can group by `IsTest` as well.

```
var groupedPersons = persons.GroupBy(person => 
                      new {
                              person.Name, 
                              person.Age, 
                              person.Address,
                              Height = person.IsTest ? 0 : person.Height,
                              person.IsTest
                           }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the ternary as part of the group by itself since the compiler can't figure out the return type of the `GroupBy` call (since it's actually two different types).

You could embed the logic inside a property on the `Person` object instead:

```
public class Person {
  public string Name { get; set; }
  public int Age { get; set; }
  public string Address { get; set; }
  public double Height { get; set; }
  public bool IsTest { get; set; }
  public double GroupProperty { get { return IsTest ? 0.0 : Height } }
}

var groupedPersons = persons.GroupBy(person =>
  new {
        person.Name,
        person.Age,
        person.Address,
        person.GroupByProperty
  }).ToList();
```

This would eliminate the `Height` property as a grouping value for all `Person` instances with `IsTest` set to `true` (since they will all share the same height).

Comment: Except your code doesn't actually use `Person`, it creates object of an anonymous type.